# Reading an image in PHP using only part of its file name

Tags: php, image, directory

I am trying to read images stored in the directory in PHP by getting only part of its name. The images are named as follows,

```
AT-1410f1654.jpg
AT-1410_1655.jpg
AT-1410_1656.jpg
AT-1410_1657.jpg
AT-1410_1658.jpg
AT-1410_1659.jpg
```

I have tried the following code below but it does not work even if I use the PHP substr() method but it also did not work,

```
    $dbImage=$row["pref"];
    $imageName=$dbImage;
    $extension=".jpg";
    $filename=$imageName.$extension;
    echo "$filename+<img src='proppics/$filename'>";
```

Any ideas on how this could be done

The Full Code

```
$limit=10; 
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("movedb") or die("Unable to select database");
$query="select * FROM properties where `name`='Beata Grande 1' & `catergory`='Villas'& `price`=202800 & `area`='Arenas'& `bedrooms`=2 & `region`='Axarquia'";
$numresults=mysql_query($query,$con);
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($numresults);
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Couldn't execute query");
echo "<center>";
echo "<p>You searched for: &quot;" . $properties . "&quot;</p>";
echo "<form name=payment action='properties_details.php'>";
echo "Results <br>";
  while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $id=$row['id'];
    $pid=$row['pref'];
    // Retrieve the balance database fields

      echo "<p>Property ID &nbsp".$pid;
      echo "<br> <p> Name &nbsp";
      echo $row["name"];
      echo "<br>  Properties &nbsp";
      echo $row["catergory"];
      echo "<br> Description &nbsp";
    // Print results
 echo "<br>";
 echo "<input type=submit name=btnbuy value=MoreDetails> ";
```

Comment: I don't see any connection between the filenames and the code, nor do I see any loop... you need to provide more details / code

Comment: I tried to create a for loop but couldnt figure how the correct technique

Comment: You must also tell us what is stored in these variables. I can't guess what `$dbImage` contains. Why do you create two variables containing `$row["pref"]`?

Comment: The image reading code comes at the end

Answer (score 0):

First, list all files in your dir using `scandir`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

then check for existing prefix using `strpos`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

```
$dir    = 'propix';
$files  = scandir($dir);
$prefix = '1410';
foreach($files as $file) {

    if(strpos($prefix) !== FALSE) { //here you are supposed to add more...

        echo $file;
    }
}
```

Comment: It gives me an error in this line     if(strpos($prefix) !== FALSE) {
Error is strpos() expects at least 2 parameters one given. According to the URL you gave should I use it as strpos($filename,$prefix)

Comment: I think it could be sorted if there is a way to automatically read the value of prefix (as presently its stored in a variable)

Answer (score 0):

How about [`glob`](http://php.net/glob)?

Your question isn't clear enough to provide a more comprehensive answer

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve.
But if you want to select only part of the filename either after the "_" or before for whatever reason, you could use PHPs explode() function.

In your case writing:

```
print explode("_", $dbImage);
```

Would have an output similar to this:

```
Array(
    [0] => AT-1410
    [1] => 1655.jpg
)
```